# overlay text on image for email templates

Tags: email-templates

I have issue with background-images working for email templates(i know background image won't work across all email templates consistently but my client want it to email with background images).
I want to add background image for for the mail template but no luck as of it as it is not supported in most of the clients.

I tried to ovelay text on image using negative margin-left and position absolute but no luck as margin-left is not supported in outlo0k,gmail and notes.

Any help/suggestions would be great

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are still some good solution for achieving background images.

In Outlook, which is one of the more difficult clients to work with this [post](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=3862) from Campaign Monitor's blog should point you in the right direction. The is a technique that uses VML to get background images working well in Outlook 2007, 2011, 2013.

The other tip is add the `!important` declaration to your CSS for Gmail to recognize the background image.

You might also want to set background colors if you're using tables with old `bgcolor` attribute setting just in case your background images don't load. That way if you have say...gray text on a blue background it still looks okay.

Finally, set you background images up as inline CSS and use media queries so on the clients like the iPad that are easier to work with you get the results you want.